# How can I change the values of an Instance after creating one with createInstance()

Tags: kotlin, reflection, instance

I need to implement a function that receives a *JsonToken* and a *KClass<*>*, this function is supposed to parse a String and in the end return an object, my problem is that I can't find a way to change the parameters values of the instance of the object I created.

`val inst = klass.createInstance()`

This will create an instance of the object with the optional parameters and I need to change the parameters to values that were found earlier in the function.

**Edit:** A bit more information about this,
the first test I need to get the code to pass is

```kotlin
val json = "{name: \"John Smith\", nr: 6453}"
val student = JsonParserReflect.parse(json, student::class) as Student
assertEquals("John Smith", student.name)
assertEquals(6453, student.nr)
```

For this I have 4 functions to remove the ", [, { and one other that parses the rest of the string. My problem is the one that parses the '{' because it has to return an object but I don't how I can create a generic object and give it the parameters and values that I got earlier.

```kotlin
override fun parseObject(tokens: JsonTokens, klass: KClass<*>): Any? {
    val jsonParams :MutableList<Any?> = mutableListOf()

    tokens.pop(OBJECT_OPEN)
    tokens.trim()
    while(tokens.current != OBJECT_END) {
        val typeName = tokens.popWordFinishedWith(COLON)
        val k = klass.members.filter { it.name == typeName}
        val k2 = k[0].typeParameters::class
        val v = parse(tokens, k2)
        jsonParams.add(v)
        if(tokens.current == COMMA) {
        tokens.pop()
        }
        else if(tokens.current == COLON) {
        tokens.pop()
        }
        else break
        tokens.trim()
    }
    tokens.pop(OBJECT_END)
    val inst = klass.createInstance()
    // If I just return inst here the params will have null as value 
    return inst
}
```

Comment: Can you show your class code and indicate which values you want to change?

Comment: ``createInstance()`` just calls the no-args constructor for the class (which can be an all-optional-parameters constructor in Kotlin). You might want to look at ``primaryConstructor``, which gives you a ``KFunction`` that you can call with your parameters: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reflection.html#constructor-references

Comment: @MarioHuizinga I have added more info to the post if that helps